# LaTeX | tikzpicture | spider web | clockwise

Tags: tikz-pgf

currently, I am very happy about a spider web solution I found in the internet. Unfortunately, I found out two problems for my use:

1. The diagram starts at 3 o'clock
2. The direction is counterclockwise

I tried out for a long time to fix it on my own (and used the search function) but was not able do fix it. Can someone please help me out and can tell me, which parts of the existing coding I have to change to

1. Start at 12 o'clock
2. Set the direction clockwise

That would be awesome :-) Thank you guys in advance. Here a MWE:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you give
% someone the link to this page, they can edit at the same
% time. See the help menu above for more info. Enjoy!
%
% Note: you can export the pdf to see the result at full
% resolution.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Spiderweb Diagram
%
% Author: Dominik Renzel
% Date; 2009-11-11
\documentclass{article}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title: Spiderweb diagram

Such a diagram defines a set of dimensions D = {D1,...,Dn} and a common scale unit 
range from 0 to a maximal value U. Each individual sample contains a sequence of 
pairs (Dx,Vx) with 0 <= Vx <= U for all Dx in D.

The diagram is rendered as a spiderweb, where the D dimension axes meet each 
other in the origin in an angle of 360/D and are each divided in U units. Each 
sample is rendered as half-opaque colored path along the particular value unit nodes 
on each dimension. Overlapping parts will be rendered in a composite color.

\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\D}{7} % number of dimensions (config option)
\newcommand{\U}{7} % number of scale units (config option)

\newdimen\R % maximal diagram radius (config option)
\R=3.5cm 
\newdimen\L % radius to put dimension labels (config option)
\L=4cm

\newcommand{\A}{360/\D} % calculated angle between dimension axes  

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \path (0:0cm) coordinate (O); % define coordinate for origin

  % draw the spiderweb
  \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
    \draw (\X*\A:0) -- (\X*\A:\R);
  }

  \foreach \Y in {0,...,\U}{
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
      \path (\X*\A:\Y*\R/\U) coordinate (D\X-\Y);
      \fill (D\X-\Y) circle (1pt);
    }
    \draw [opacity=0.3] (0:\Y*\R/\U) \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
        -- (\X*\A:\Y*\R/\U)
    } -- cycle;
  }

  % define labels for each dimension axis (names config option)
  \path (1*\A:\L) node (L1) {\tiny Security};
  \path (2*\A:\L) node (L2) {\tiny Content Quality};
  \path (3*\A:\L) node (L3) {\tiny Performance};
  \path (4*\A:\L) node (L4) {\tiny Stability};
  \path (5*\A:\L) node (L5) {\tiny Usability};
  \path (6*\A:\L) node (L6) {\tiny Generality};
  \path (7*\A:\L) node (L7) {\tiny Popularity};

  % for each sample case draw a path around the web along concrete values
  % for the individual dimensions. Each node along the path is labeled
  % with an identifier using the following scheme:
  %
  %   D<d>-<v>, dimension <d> a number between 1 and \D (#dimensions) and
  %             value <v> a number between 0 and \U (#scale units)
  %
  % The paths will be drawn half-opaque, so that overlapping parts will be
  % rendered in a composite color.

  % Example Case 1 (red)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 0/7; D2 (Content Quality): 5/7; D3 (Performance): 0/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 6/7; D5 (Usability): 0/7; D6 (Generality): 5/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 0/7
  \draw [color=red,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-0) --
    (D2-5) --
    (D3-0) --
    (D4-6) --
    (D5-0) --
    (D6-5) --
    (D7-0) -- cycle;

  % Example Case 2 (green)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 2/7; D2 (Content Quality): 2/7; D3 (Performance): 5/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 1/7; D5 (Usability): 4/7; D6 (Generality): 1/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 7/7
  \draw [color=green,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-2) --
    (D2-2) --
    (D3-5) --
    (D4-1) --
    (D5-4) --
    (D6-1) --
    (D7-7) -- cycle;

  % Example Case 3 (blue)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 1/7; D2 (Content Quality): 7/7; D3 (Performance): 4/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 4/7; D5 (Usability): 3/7; D6 (Generality): 5/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 2/7
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-1) --
    (D2-7) --
    (D3-4) --
    (D4-4) --
    (D5-3) --
    (D6-5) --
    (D7-2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Spiderweb Diagram (\D~Dimensions, \U-Notch Scale, 3 Samples)}
\label{fig:spiderweb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? **UPDATED**: made stupid mistake, sorry. **EDIT**: All I did was to look for the `\X` variables, reversed their sign (clockwise vs. counter-clockwise) and shifted the whole thing by 90 degrees. Originally I misread 3pm as 30 degrees, and hence introduced an unnecessary shift of `\X` by -1. I also shifted the arguments of the various `\path (-n*\A+90:\L) node (Ln) {\tiny ...};` by 90 and introduced a - sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\begin{comment}
:Title: Spiderweb diagram

Such a diagram defines a set of dimensions D = {D1,...,Dn} and a common scale unit 
range from 0 to a maximal value U. Each individual sample contains a sequence of 
pairs (Dx,Vx) with 0 <= Vx <= U for all Dx in D.

The diagram is rendered as a spiderweb, where the D dimension axes meet each 
other in the origin in an angle of 360/D and are each divided in U units. Each 
sample is rendered as half-opaque colored path along the particular value unit nodes 
on each dimension. Overlapping parts will be rendered in a composite color.
\end{comment}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\D}{7} % number of dimensions (config option)
\newcommand{\U}{7} % number of scale units (config option)

\newdimen\R % maximal diagram radius (config option)
\R=3.5cm 
\newdimen\L % radius to put dimension labels (config option)
\L=4cm

\newcommand{\A}{360/\D} % calculated angle between dimension axes  

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \path (0:0cm) coordinate (O); % define coordinate for origin

  % draw the spiderweb
  \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
    \draw ({-(\X)*\A+90}:0) -- ({-(\X)*\A+90}:\R);
  }

  \foreach \Y in {0,...,\U}{
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
      \path ({-(\X)*\A+90}:\Y*\R/\U) coordinate (D\X-\Y);
      \fill (D\X-\Y) circle (1pt);
    }
    \draw [opacity=0.3] (90:\Y*\R/\U) \foreach \X in {1,...,\D}{
        -- ({-(\X)*\A+90}:\Y*\R/\U)
    } -- cycle;
  }

  % define labels for each dimension axis (names config option)
  \path (-1*\A+90:\L) node (L1) {\tiny Security};
  \path (-2*\A+90:\L) node (L2) {\tiny Content Quality};
  \path (-3*\A+90:\L) node (L3) {\tiny Performance};
  \path (-4*\A+90:\L) node (L4) {\tiny Stability};
  \path (-5*\A+90:\L) node (L5) {\tiny Usability};
  \path (-6*\A+90:\L) node (L6) {\tiny Generality};
  \path (-7*\A+90:\L) node (L7) {\tiny Popularity};

  % for each sample case draw a path around the web along concrete values
  % for the individual dimensions. Each node along the path is labeled
  % with an identifier using the following scheme:
  %
  %   D<d>-<v>, dimension <d> a number between 1 and \D (#dimensions) and
  %             value <v> a number between 0 and \U (#scale units)
  %
  % The paths will be drawn half-opaque, so that overlapping parts will be
  % rendered in a composite color.

  % Example Case 1 (red)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 0/7; D2 (Content Quality): 5/7; D3 (Performance): 0/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 6/7; D5 (Usability): 0/7; D6 (Generality): 5/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 0/7
  \draw [color=red,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-0) --
    (D2-5) --
    (D3-0) --
    (D4-6) --
    (D5-0) --
    (D6-5) --
    (D7-0) -- cycle;

  % Example Case 2 (green)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 2/7; D2 (Content Quality): 2/7; D3 (Performance): 5/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 1/7; D5 (Usability): 4/7; D6 (Generality): 1/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 7/7
  \draw [color=green,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-2) --
    (D2-2) --
    (D3-5) --
    (D4-1) --
    (D5-4) --
    (D6-1) --
    (D7-7) -- cycle;

  % Example Case 3 (blue)
  %
  % D1 (Security): 1/7; D2 (Content Quality): 7/7; D3 (Performance): 4/7;
  % D4 (Stability): 4/7; D5 (Usability): 3/7; D6 (Generality): 5/7;
  % D7 (Popularity): 2/7
  \draw [color=blue,line width=1.5pt,opacity=0.5]
    (D1-1) --
    (D2-7) --
    (D3-4) --
    (D4-4) --
    (D5-3) --
    (D6-5) --
    (D7-2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Spiderweb Diagram (\D~Dimensions, \U-Notch Scale, 3 Samples)}
\label{fig:spiderweb}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works. Not even 5 min. ago and you answered my question. Now I can finalize my section and can go to bed (1am) :-) Thanks again and have a good day.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Thanks again - I was really frustrated about this clockwise / start point issue! :-)